# Implement Modal Dialog Box in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

Anyone have any experience creating a modal dialog box using AJAX and ASP.NET MVC?  I am looking to create a Yes/Cancel confirmation dialog when a user deletes an item.  In standard ASP.NET I could just use the ModalPopup extender, but I am not sure how to do this in MVC.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) for jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

I've found [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/) [for jQuery] to be very easy to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I like the Dialog in [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Easy to use, clean.